# Boot WinPE from usb-stick using Command Prompt

Tags: boot, multi-boot, dism, winpe

I'm using a usb-stick with WinPE and dism to apply a Win8.1 image (*.wim) to a pc. After applying the image, the pc boots with Win8.1 and a few scripts are executed automatically doing some installation and configuration work.

To save these settings, i want to capture an image of the complete C drive using dism /capture-image (not recimg!). Capturing the image should be done automatically after the execution of the last script, so i need a way to change the boot options from command prompt.

What i have already tried

- diskpart: flag usb-stick as active volume -> Win8.1 boots
- bcdedit: `bcdedit /copy {current} /d „WinPE“`, `bcdedit /set {[id]} path F:\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`, `bcdedit /set {[id]} device partition=F:`, `bcdedit /set {[id]} osdevice partition=F:` -> WinPE is showing in boot menu, ut "automatic repair" starts instead of WinPE.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong or how else i can boot from usb-stick using command prompt?

Comment: I'm having the same problem from the answer on my question here: [Programmatically restart computer and boot into flash drive](//superuser.com/a/1327340) - were you able to fix this?